# Getting a "Service not registered" error when trying to unbind a service

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a service receiver to take care of callbacks related to BLE GATT events (connecting, disconnecting, etc).

In situations where I kill the BLE device to simulate a dropout, the disconnect event fires, and my call to `context.unbindService(serviceConnection)` fails. I've checked for a few of the obvious errors (different contexts, null service connection, etc), and can't find the error. Why am I getting this exception?

Here's the trace:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.ktest, PID: 6372
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: com.example.ktest.ble.BLEConnectionManager$serviceConnection$1@493960
> at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1602)
> at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1710)
> at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:717)
> at com.example.ktest.ble.BLEConnectionManager.unBindService(BLEConnectionManager.kt:81)
> at com.example.ktest.foo.FooActivity.disconnect(FooActivity.kt:268)
> at com.example.ktest.foo.FooActivity.access$disconnect(FooActivity.kt:47)
> at com.example.ktest.foo.FooActivity$gattUpdateReceiver$1$onReceive$1.run(FooActivity.kt:190)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6863)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

Here's the disconnect function that's called as per the trace:

```
private fun disconnect() {
    BLEConnectionManager.unBindService(this@FooActivity) // FAILS HERE
    unregisterServiceReceiver()
    val intent = Intent(this, ConnectDeviceActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
    finish() // close activity
}
```

The service was bound using the same context (from `FooActivity.onStart()`):

```
BLEConnectionManager.bindService(this@FooActivity)
```

So there are no problems when `BLEConnectionManager.bindService()` is called:

```
fun bindService(context: Context) {
    if (serviceConnection != null && isBound) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Service is already bound")
    } else {
        val gattServiceIntent = Intent(context, BLEService::class.java)
        if (context != null) {
            isBound = context.bindService(
                gattServiceIntent,
                serviceConnection,
                Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "BLEService now bound, isBound is now $isBound")
    }
}
```

Here's the `BLEConnectionManager.unBindService()`

```
fun unBindService(context: Context) {
     // NOTE I've logged the service and connection here, they're non-null and BLE works fine in this Activity
    if (serviceConnection != null && isBound) context.unbindService(serviceConnection)
}
```

So what have I missed, and what am I doing wrong that causes the exception?

Answer (score 1):

I was calling unbind too many times (on a service that had previously unbound and hadn't been bound again since). This was because I had forgotten to set my BLEConnectionManager `isBound` flag in that class' unbind method. Whoops.